# Weighted Euclidean Distance while Merging Feature Vectors?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, vector, euclidean-distance, cosine-similarity

I have two groups of features (describing an image, in a machine learning context). The first group A, consisting of 3 features, and group B consisting of 15 features.

```
A = [f1, f2, f3]
B = [f4, f5, .., f18]
```

Currently, I am simply concatenating both groups to a combined feature group C:

```
C = [f1, f2, f3, f4, ..., f18]
```

I want to compare images using the resulting feature groups Cn (nx18 dimensions) via Euclidean distances.

```
dist = np.linalg.norm(C1-Cn)
```

B has 5x the number of features compared to A and I am wondering how to weight groups A and B equally within the Euclidean Distance calculation? I thought about doing C=A+A+A+A+A+B, or concatenating the unit vector of A and unit vector of B. Are these approaches correct, or is there a better approach?

```
Goal_Dist = np.mean([np.linalg.norm(A1-An), np.linalg.norm(B1-Bn)])
```

(Goal distance as function, however due to certain constraints I need to express this function only through a combined vector C.)

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to overcome the problem you have. The first one I thought was to use Mahalanobis Distance rather than Euclidean, and the second one was to scale the data before you concat and then do the calculation on concatanated matrix.

**Mahalanobis Distance**

Mahalanobis Distance is a statistical distance measure that computes a vector point of dimension N let's say to the mean using covariance matrix as a scaling factor. You can think of this as a multivariate application of standardization. When covariance matrix is an identity matrix, this reduces to an Euclidean distance. You can further read it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).

**Euclidean Distance via Scaling**

Without having the knowledge of your feautres, I cannot directly refer to one exact technique. You can use variety of scalers and normalization techniques to overcome this problem before or after concataneting the sets. However, you should choose a proper scaling technique according to your behavior and structure of your data. Some useful "first go-to" methods are:

- Standard Scaler
- MinMax Scaler

Other than normalization or scaling you may try dimension reduction and then concat equal amount of features of the sets. The dimension reduction can be done with PCA, tSNE, IsoMap, ...

Comment: I agree with everything, it depends on how you want to approach the problem. Scaling is necessary to obtain a meaningful distance. I would like to add that you also have the option to use the max norm which is invariant when it comes to vector dimensionality.